# What advantages and drawbacks does Enumerable.SequenceEqual(list1, list2) has against list1.All(list2.Contains)?

Tags: performance, linq

My colleague was reviewing a pull request and the conversation came out around `Enumerable.SequenceEqual(list1, list2)` vs `list1.All(list2.Contains)` in this case both lists were `strings`. But I wouldn't limit the question to just `string`

**What advantages and drawbacks does `Enumerable.SequenceEqual(list1, list2)` have against `list1.All(list2.Contains)`?**

It could be argued that this is opinion-based, but underlying mechanisms are different, and one of them should perform better in certain cases also should have other nuances where it is a better fit.

P.S My preference goes to `Enumerable.SequenceEqual` simply because it better describes what it does.

Comment: Well, they don't do the same thing, for starters. First agree on the semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SequenceEqual method determines whether two IEnumerable sequences contain the same objects in the same order. So you have to sort the objects and then call `SequenceEqual`. Unfortunately this solution requires that you sort the items somehow, and that may not always be possible. Or you go with an extension like `ComparableSequenceEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list1, IEnumerable<T> list2)`.

To go into `SequenceEqual` I have two examples for you here.

This would return **true**:

```
Pet pet1 = new Pet { Name = "Turbo", Age = 2 };
Pet pet2 = new Pet { Name = "Peanut", Age = 8 };

List<Pet> pets1 = new List<Pet> { pet1, pet2 };
List<Pet> pets2 = new List<Pet> { pet1, pet2 };

bool equal = pets1.SequenceEqual(pets2);
```

This would return **false**:

```
Pet pet1 = new Pet() { Name = "Turbo", Age = 2 };
Pet pet2 = new Pet() { Name = "Peanut", Age = 8 };

List<Pet> pets1 = new List<Pet> { pet1, pet2 };
List<Pet> pets2 = new List<Pet> 
                  { 
                     new Pet { Name = "Turbo", Age = 2 },
                     new Pet { Name = "Peanut", Age = 8 } 
                  };

bool equal = pets1.SequenceEqual(pets2);
```

These sequences contain identical data, but since the objects they contain have different references, the sequences are not considered the same.

Since I don't know your use case exactly, I would rather proceed with the second option `list1.All(list2.Contains)`.